# How to download file from Onedrive in NIFI

Tags: apache-nifi, onedrive

I am trying to download zip files from the thrid party Onedrive.

How can I download the zip files through nifi? What kind of processor should I use?

Comment: you need to call Onedrive REST api's to download content using InvokeHTTP processor. 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_get_content?view=odsp-graph-online

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@duolanierdunone

The solution you are looking for here is InvokeHttp to make an API call suggested in comments above.

You can find some nice templates for InvokeHttp here:
https://github.com/steven-matison/NiFi-Templates